New motherboard doesn't recognise AMD Radeon RX 6700XT graphics card that is recognized and works on older computer
ALMOST SOLVED THEN BROKE AGAIN
Please see answer..
TLDR; It seems weird to me that a 1 year old graphics card would work fine on a 7 year old motherboard but not on a brand new motherboard.
New PC:

Nvidia GTX 1080 is recognised
AMD Radeon RX 6700XT is not recognised

Old PC:

Nvidia GTX 1080 is recognised
AMD Radeon RX 6700XT is recognised


More details…
I've been building a new computer and I'm trying to use a new (to me) AMD 6700XT graphics card that was running fine in my older computer when I played games as recently as last weekend. When I put the card in my new build at first it wasn't recognized by the motherboard (i.e. no video output on the graphics card, only the motherboard's HDMI socket with the integrated graphics).
I thought it was just being weird because I'm installing Windows for the first time. So I install Windows using the integrated graphics. The graphics card is plugged into the motherboard's PCI-E x16 slot. I install the AMD drivers and then suddenly the computer can see the graphics card in the Task Manager.
So then I plug the HDMI into the graphics card and it works all that evening. I test a game on it. Then I boot it the next morning and it doesn't work. There's no output on the video card. I go into Windows and it can't see it in the device manager either.
It's as if it's invisible to it. I've reinstalled the graphics driver and still it doesn't see it. It was a factory clean reinstall.
At first I was thinking somehow the graphics card got fried so I take the graphics card out and tried it on my other PC and it works fine!
I have an nVidia GTX1080 as well, also installed in the older computer, and when I try this in the new computer it works just fine. So it's like the new motherboard only likes nVidia and it doesn't like AMD.
Is there anything I'm missing about what could be wrong here? I'm thinking of using DDU to uninstall the drivers and try once more to get the 6700XT running on the new PC.
Both systems are running 650W power supplies with updated BIOSes. New PC is running AMD Ryzen 5 7600X with 32GB of DDR5 RAM. Old PC is running Intel i7-8700K with 32GB of DDR4 RAM.


This photo here got me suspicious and thinking..


+1 on posting a question that is very well explained. That said, I'm stumped on what it can be. Your explanation has at least ruled out all the questions that popped in my mind, so that is a good thing. You could try a BIOS update. Maybe you got Windows Update that updated the graphics driver or chipset, and that update expects a newer version of the BIOS. That's all I can think of at the moment.

Something you should check is whether you even see a BIOS at all with the AMD GPU; Try spamming the delete key to actually enter the BIOS too. If you can see a BIOS and then video goes away by the time Windows boots it's surely an OS issue. If you get no BIOS then it's probably a hardware/BIOS/firmware issue.

@LPChip hah, should have mentioned, already tried a BIOS update!

@Romen from what I remember it couldn't see the GPU in BIOS either no.

Weird question, your new computer, does it have the same PSU as the old one or a different one? The new system will require more power, so it may simply be that you are just on the line of not supplying enough power to the GPU and that it therefor isn't showing up. Also, the PSU can simply be faulty.

@LPChip different PSUs but both are 650W. I should have a solid 100W+ buffer with my calculations and it worked on the first night :/

Your PSU may be faulty, I should see if you can test that by disconnecting as much hardware (USB etc) so you have the minimum attached, and see if that changes things. Keep in mind that after windows is installed, it will do windows updates, and that will install more stuff that makes the computer use more power, although that should not change for the BIOS, but you mentioned you never got that working in the first place. You can also try using energy savings power management to lower the CPU electrical needs, and see if that makes the PSU suddenly detectable.

@LPChip OK, I do note that the minimum PSU for the 6700XT is 650W whereas for the GTX 1080 it's 500W, so I guess if anything at all is wrong with the PSU in the the new PC it could end up being right on the limit for the 6700XT but still good enough for the GTX 1080. I will try again tonight to swap them over and see if the 6700XT works.. but if not.. Maybe the cheapest thing I can do is get another PSU maybe 750W or 800W and see if it starts working after that, in the mean time just run the GPUs swapped over.

Yes, but your processor and the rest need power too. I'm now more convinced that its the PSU. To be on the safe side, get 800W to 1000W. You can call a shop and ask them if they are willing if you bring your pc to them, that they hook up a new PSU to test, and if it works, you buy it. Most shops with a workshop will have no problem with that.

@EM-Creations, You couldn't "see the GPU in the BIOS" but you saw the BIOS? Plug your HDMI cable into the GPU, if it's plugged into the motherboard port you're telling the system to prefer the integrated graphics. You have to have nothing plugged into the integrated video to give the PCIe GPU a chance at being the primary GPU at POST. Then with the monitor(s) only connected to the dedicated GPU let us know if the BIOS shows up at all.

@LPChip, the PSU recommendations for GPUs always account for a typical CPU and the rest of the system. The 6700XT only draws ~230W, so the 650W recommendation is allowing for ~400W of other stuff in the system. I doubt the problem is that the GPU doesn't have enough power but you could be right that the PSU is faulty.

Earlier in the question you note the AMD GPU shows up in the Task Manager. The Task Manager doesn't display hardware, but running software. Do you perhaps mean you could see the AMD card in the Device Manager? If so, please correct this in your question.

Task Manager does show all of your GPUs in the "Performance" tab, for Windows 10 and 11.

@Romen only 1 cable was plugged in at any one time, a single HDMI. I didn't have anything in both the iGPU and GPU at the same time. So I was 100% sure what had video output and what didn't.

@music2myear doesn't appear in either Task Manager (Performance Tab for GPU utilisation and temperature) or anywhere in the device manager.

I think I have solved the problem.. Just doing some testing and I'll post the answer. Your comments got me looking at the PSU closely and I think that's where the problem was!

Turned on the PC again today.. No video output again! Gonna try a new PSU if that doesn't fix it return the motherboard.

Previous answer.. Worked for a few days then back to the same problem
Thank you to everyone in the comments. It got me thinking about the PSU and giving it more scrutiny than I had previously.
Now working:

The two PCI E connectors I was using were 6 + 2 pin, both of them had broken retaining clips (the PSU was bought used but still fully functional). The graphics card I previously used with this was an Nvidia GTX 1070 which used an 8 pin PCI E connector so I was using one of them. When I installed the AMD 6700XT I pulled the first spare PCI E wire I saw in the bundle of PSU wires laying at the bottom of the case which was another 6 + 2 pin, I did what I've normally done with many a PSU before and connected 1 6 + 2 pin wire and the other 6 + 2 pin with the spare 2 pins dangling and thought nothing of it. Only when I went to try again today I payed close attention to the fact that the broken retaining clip did not line up with where the GPU was expecting it to be.
See this photo:

I dug around in the bundle of PSU wires and found 2 others which were just 6 pin so.. I replaced one of the 6 + 2 pin wires I was previously using for the 6 pin connection on the GPU with one of the 6 pin PSU wires.
I then plugged the HDMI cable into the GPU turned on the PC and it instantly recognised it..
So I guess the problem came down to a quirk of this XFX PSU that if you have a 6 pin connection on the GPU you need to specifically use the 6 pin PSU wire.
Anyone got any technical details about why this is so? My thoughts are that maybe the electrical engineers who designed this thought if a signal isn't seen on all of the pins to not power the cable as some kind of safety precaution, thinking it's not plugged in correctly. Maybe it would have worked if I had jumped the connection between pins 8 and 4. And looking at the spec of the PCI power connector in the 6 pin model pin 2 isn't powered but most manufacturers provide 12V to it anyway (apparently) but maybe XFX didn't in this case and that contributed to it.
The modular PSU in my older PC has 6 + 2 pin PCI E cables which work fine with this.

This area is reserved for answers, not further questions. Please keep that in mind as you answer. If you have a different question, post it as its own question. If this question is part of your original question, add it there.
